# Wordpress Dashboard Feed Widget - how do I open feed in a new window?

Tags: wordpress

I am making a Wordpress dashboard widget to show feeds from The Onion. The below code works fine - but how can I open the feed in a new window. I assume it is a target=_blank ..... but where and how?

```html
/** START The Onion Dashboard */

add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'onion_dashboard_add_widgets' );
function onion_dashboard_add_widgets() {
 wp_add_dashboard_widget( 'dw_dashboard_widget_onion', __( 'The Onion', 'dw' ), 'dw_dashboard_widget_onion_handler' );
}


function dw_dashboard_widget_onion_handler() {
 $feeds = array(
  array(
   'url'          => 'https://www.theonion.com/rss',
   'items'        =>15,
   'show_summary' => 1,
   'show_author'  => 0,
   'show_date'    => 1,
      
  ),
   
 );

 wp_dashboard_primary_output( 'dw_dashboard_widget_onion', $feeds );
};

/** END The Onion Dashboard */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no pretty way to achieve this since neither `wp_widget_rss_output` nor `wp_dashboard_primary_output` offer any filters or options for this. You can solve it in a hacky way:

- buffer the output of `wp_dashboard_primary_output`
- modify the buffer to add your desired `target`
- echo the modified buffer

To achieve this, edit the function like so:

```
function dw_dashboard_widget_onion_handler() {
    $feeds = array(
        array(
            'url'          => 'https://www.theonion.com/rss',
            'items'        =>15,
            'show_summary' => 1,
            'show_author'  => 0,
            'show_date'    => 1,

        ),

    );

    ob_start(); // start output buffering
    wp_dashboard_primary_output( 'dw_dashboard_widget_onion', $feeds );
    $buffer = ob_get_clean(); // get the buffer without printing the content

    // add the target attribute to the a-tag:
    $result = str_replace("<a class='rsswidget'",
                          "<a class='rsswidget' target='_blank'", $buffer);
    echo $result;
};
```